# how to echo contents from body to header for meta tag

Tags: php

I am trying something not sure how to go about it

I have a header.php file

I included it in the pages so now i want to add meta tag but don't want the same description and keyword.

If I use a div tag  where I place the contents in the body  I want to show from the description in search engine of that page then echo it in the header file would that work and what is the coding to use?

Thanks hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `header.php` file, define a function that creates the header:

```
function header($description, $keywords) {
    ...
    echo "<meta name='description' content='$description' />";
    echo "<meta name='keywords' content='$keywords' />";
    ...
}
```

Then the pages that use this will do:

```
require 'header.php';
header($this_description, $these_keywords);
```

It can later uses these same variables when it creates the `DIV`.

Comment: Thanks for answering how can i turn this variables to  creates a DIV

Comment: Something like: `echo "<div>Description: $this_description</div>;"`

Comment: <div <?php echo $this_description; ?>%;">     <<< like this?

Answer (score 0):

in your header.php:

```
    echo '<meta name="description" content = "'.$description.'">';
echo '<meta name="keywords" content = "'.$keywords.'">';
```

in your index.php or other pages that use the header.php file:

```
$description = "This is a cool site about simplicity of PHP :)";
$keywords = "PHP,Specify, THE, $variables, before, Include";
include('header.php');
//other elements :)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your page put this

```
$pageTitle = 'Services';
$keyword = "Books a Party Hall and Room Rentals in Toronto";
$description = "Books a Party Hall and Room Rentals in Toronto. Halls rental for Events, Adult & Children's Birthday Parties, Photography, Wedding, Music and Fashion Show Shoots, Corporate Presentations, Baby Showers, Going Away and Engagement Parties."; 
include 'header.php';
```

in your header put this code

```
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keyword; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
```